# rails 3.2 ActionMailer after_callback message.body not working

Tags: ruby, actionmailer

In my Rails 3.2.13 application I am saving every mail using after_callback mail|message object

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    include AbstractController::Callbacks
    after_filter :track
    def track
        interaction= Interaction.create(
                from: message.from,
                to: message.to,
                body: message.decode_body,
                subject: message.subject
        )
    end
end
```

which is working perfect for all the mails except mails with attachments. there, body(message.body,message.decode_body) is giving blank string.

any idea?

Comment: Where's `message` defined and what does it hold?

Comment: message and mail objects will be there in action_mailer callback. for non-attachment mails, they hold all details about the mail which is just sent..like to,cc,bcc,subject,content-type,sent_at etc. all other values are accessible except body if mail has attachments

Comment: have you looked at message.body.raw_source or message.attachments

Comment: @phoet I have checked both. message.body.raw_source is returning nil nad attachments returns an array of attachments.but not the body part.

Comment: well, that leaves two options, a) your code is broken (very likely) b) actionmailer is broken (highly unlikely)